# What's the best/fastest way to divide a database into smaller one (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a single database with all my clients and I need to divide it into multiple "little" databases each with one client for post-treatment purposes.
(I have a "clients" table from where all the foreign keys are linked)

The hard part is that this process should run daily and be "fast" how can I do that?

I already try to copy my database into multiple sub database and use the cascade delete to only keep the client I need on the small database but the process takes at least 30 min.
I've used `mysqldump` to generate the original file (around 3Go) that's copied into the small table and `cat file.sql | mysql -u...` to right the file in the bases. Those operations are run in a node process to parallelize (`child_process.exec`)the tasks but it's still really slow.

Comment: Why do you feel the /need/ to do this?  
You have a single, working database - why would you /want/ to break it into smaller, less manageable pieces?

Comment: Hi, because those small bases will be used to feed a power bi board open to the client so we need to have a base with only their data

Comment: @Bahaldrish Why can't you filter the data per-client? Are you giving your clients physical copies of these databases?

Comment: @Dai because I've around 140 tables link to another and filtering is pretty hard and to make sure client really can't access to data they'll be able to do query themselves

Comment: @Bahaldrish "filtering is pretty hard" - perhaps for some... Lots of DBMS support row-level security now.

Comment: If you are co-hosting different Clients' data in one database, you really should be using Row-Based Security to keep them away from one another's data.  
With that properly in place, you won't /need/ to split the data at all.

Comment: "*filtering is pretty hard*" - similarly to filtering the data to just a specific client to be copied into those smaller specific tables. As you see, this process you're trying to accomplish is not really any easier. Any reason you couldn't create Views to emulate some form of row-level security (like Dai and Phill mentioned)?

Comment: If row-level security is 'required', start with split-up datasets.

Comment: Why is  "filtering hard"?  Are you letting the in-secure customers write there own filters?